# How can I move files from a Mac to an external DD, without lost the tags?

Tags: python, macos, shutil

In some case, tags are lost when I move files from a Mac to an external DD.

(f is the file)

If I use shutil.move("/Users/gilles/Desktop/" + f, "/Users/gilles/Douments/"), it's ok
but
if I use shutil.move("/Users/gilles/Desktop/" + f, "/Volume/DDEXTERNAL/"), the file is moved correctly, but the tags are lost.

Comment: It transpires that *shutil.move()* does not copy Tags. However, the macOS command *mv* **will** copy any Tags.

Comment: Perhaps, but here, I want work python ;-)

Comment: Is calling *mv* from Python a reasonable compromise?

Comment: I must try ! (or I can recode all the program with bash)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, file tags are stored in `.DS_Store` file within the filesystem. When you move a file out from its originating filesystem, tag information will not be there anymore unless you re-create the `.DS_Store` in the new location. There are couple of python packages that deal with manipulating that file but can't say anything about how well they are suited for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is double positive !   
• I did not know vers the tags were stored.   
• I have a track for other search.

Comment: .DS_Store holds folder-specific metadata (e.g., its preferred layout in Finder). It does not store attributes of any of the files in the same directory

Comment: There are multiple references here and there that point out that the tags are stored either in dsstore *and* EA on the filesystem  -  For example, this was the first hit; https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46614/adding-tags-to-files-in-os-x-how-to-use-where-are-tags-stored-and-will-they-w and the accepted answer explicitly said that.  Thus, the added "Afaik" ..

Comment: @rasjani I don't know how tags are stored. On my macOS 13.2.1 system I have just tagged a file. I can see the tag in Finder. However, there is no .DS_Store file in the directory that contains the tagged file. This is all very mysterious

Comment: Yeah, i tried the same on non mac fs and it created a "._${filename}" and the tag is in there. ```rasjani@myhostname /Volumes/TRANSFER$ ls -lat *foo*
-rwx------  1 rasjani  staff  4096 Feb 22 15:22 ._foo
-rwx------@ 1 rasjani  staff     0 Feb 22 15:22 foo
rasjani@myhostname /Volumes/TRANSFER$ strings ._foo
Mac OS X
ATTR
$com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags
bplist00
FUCKMETHERIGHTWAY
This resource fork intentionally left blank```

Comment: tagname is shown after bplist00 ;)

Comment: @rasjani Looks like it *may* have previously been true that tags were stored in .DS_Store but that is no longer the case. The technology is known as Extended Attributes - which includes Tags. The *xattr* command is a good starting place

Answer (score -1):

When files are moved on a *nix type system (don't know about Windows) the "move" can be achieved by merely updating the source and target directories with relevant inode data **providing** the source and target are on the same filesystem. The file (its contents) don't actually move anywhere.

However, if the source and target directories are on different filesystems (as seems to be the case here) then the file is copied to the target and removed from the source. This is described in the *man* page for *mv*. In such a case the target file behaves as if it has been newly created

Comment: I agree with your comments, but I expect that there is a method who copy also specifics datas.
(Sorry for my bad english !)

Comment: @Gilles57 Please explain what you mean by "specifics datas". Maybe give an example

Comment: I mean literals tags and colored 'badges', specificities of MacOS